Limits in ggplot2 trans_new function for facets
I am trying to create faceted density plots with one (or more) of the variables transformed by my own function log10p_trans:
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape)
library(forcats)
library(scales)

log10p_trans <- trans_new(name = "log10p_trans",
                          transform = function(x) log10(x + 1),
                          inverse = function(x) 10^x - 1)

rex <- data.frame("value1" = rexp(100, rate = 1),
                  "value2" = rexp(100, rate = 2))
rex_pivot <- data.frame(pivot_longer(rex, cols = 1:2))

ggplot(rex_pivot, aes(x = value, y = ..density..)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_wrap(facets = ~name, scales = "free_x") +
  ggh4x::scale_x_facet(
    name == "value1",
    trans = log10p_trans)

So far so good:

However, the problem happens when I set limits to the x values, they are not properly adjusted (they suddenly end).
ggplot(rex_pivot, aes(x = value, y = ..density..)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_wrap(facets = ~name, scales = "free_x") +
  ggh4x::scale_x_facet(
    name == "value1",
    trans = log10p_trans,
    limits = c(0, 0.5))


What can I do to fix that?

Ok, I found a way: just use facetted_pos_scales from ggh4x package:
ggplot(rex_pivot, aes(x = value, y = ..density..)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_wrap(facets = ~name, scales = "free_x") +
  ggh4x::scale_x_facet(
    name == "value1",
    trans = log10p_trans) +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(x = list(name == "value1" ~ 
                                        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5))))



